# taylor expansion of an expression in matlab

Tags: matlab

I create this code to calculate something for me. At the end I need to compute the roots of Eq1 and Eq2, but because they are nonlinear I deside to compute their taylor expansion first and then compute their roots.
But I get  error.

```
clc
clear
close all
format short g
syms x
%% Initilaizing
N=9;%input('Please enter the filter order: ');
Rl=20;%input('Please enter the value of Return Loss(RL) in dB:  ');
IL=60;%input('Please enter the value of Insertion Loss(IL) in dB:  ');
Fp=18;%input('Please enter the Band-Edge Frequency in GHz:  ');
%% Definition Functions
Omega0=fminbnd(@(OM0)Func(OM0,Rl,IL,N),0,10,optimset('Tolx',1e-500));
epsilon=1/sqrt(10^(Rl/10)-1);
ILn=10^(0.1*IL);
TempFunc=@(x)real(1+epsilon^2*(cosh((N-3)*acosh(x*sqrt((Omega0^2 -1)/(Omega0^2 -x^2)))+3*acosh(x)))^2-ILn);
Omega1=fzero(TempFunc,1);
Frequency=[Omega0;Omega1;Omega0*Fp;Omega1*Fp;N];
Freq={'Infinite Attenuation(rad)';'Band-Edge Frequency(rad)';'Infinite Attenuation(GHz)';'Band-Edge Frequency(GHz)';'Order'};
Results=table(Freq,Frequency)

Eq1=@(x) 1+1j.*epsilon.*cosh((N-3).*acosh((x./1j).*sqrt((Omega0^2 -1)./(Omega0^2 -(x./1j).^2)))+3.*acosh(x./1j));
Eq2=@(x) 1-1j.*epsilon.*cosh((N-3).*acosh((x./1j).*sqrt((Omega0^2 -1)./(Omega0^2 -(x./1j).^2)))+3.*acosh(x./1j));

taylor(Eq1,'order',50)
```

This is the function that I use:

```
function Returned=Func(OM0,Rl,IL,N)
%% Main Section
epsilon=1/sqrt(10^(Rl/10)-1);
Omega=@(OM0) sqrt(OM0.^2+((N-3)/3).*OM0.*sqrt(OM0.^2 -1)) ;
Fn=@(OM0) real(cosh((N-3).*acosh(Omega(OM0).*sqrt((OM0.^2 -1)./(OM0.^2 -Omega(OM0).^2)))+3.*acosh(Omega(OM0))));
ILoss=@(OM0)  real((1+epsilon^2.*Fn(OM0).^2));
[~,Temp]=fminbnd(ILoss,OM0,10,optimset('Tolx',1e-250));
Returned=abs(Temp-10^( IL/10));
end
```

This is the error:

```
Error using symengine (line 58)
Cannot compute a Taylor expansion of the input.
Error in sym/taylor (line 133)
    tSym = mupadmex('symobj::taylor',f.s,x.s,a.s,options);
Error in OptimizingOmega0 (line 52)
taylor(Eq1,x,50)
```

Please help me how can I earn thr polynomial coefficients of Eq1,2 for computing roots.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the [built-in](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) numerical solvers to solve the nonlinear equation?

Comment: because this kind of solver that u say just give me one root.but this equation for N=9 must have 9 root.i see that from the paper that i'm working on it